# Qual a relação entre OOP e segurança do código?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, segurança

Existe algum fundamento achar que um estilo de programar orientado a objetos é mais seguro que o estrutural?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Vou responder a parte que dá para responder aqui. Ficar listando as formas de ataque, algo que é mutável,  não leva a lugar algum e este tipo de resposta não faz parte da filosofia do *site*, além de ser muito amplo, sem contexto. Além disto está misturando assunto, termos, então ficaria difícil responder tudo. Aqui tem algumas boas fontes sobre segurança, basta procurar. Para ter entendimento real tem que estudar o assunto profundamente.

Não há relação direta entre o paradigma de programação e segurança. A segurança de acesso à memória e eventualmente de dado pode influenciar de forma mais direta. A forma como cada um programa e a qualidade dos programadores influencia de forma direta.

Nem mesmo vi um estudo que mostre que há relação indireta. Algumas pessoas dirão que OOP tornou o código mais organizado, outros dirão que tornou o código mais complexo. Pode haver alguma relação, mas é muito frágil e difícil de medir de forma objetiva.

Pegando o caso do PHP a melhoria da segurança ocorrida ao longo do tempo tem mais a ver com correção de *bugs*, melhores bibliotecas, eventualmente melhor informação do que a introdução de OOP. Não há um característica incluída na linguagem por causa da orientação a objeto que ajudou a segurança ser melhor. Nunca foi objetivo do paradigma fazer isto.

Orientação a contratos pode influenciar de forma indireta já que este "paradigma" busca códigos mais confiáveis. Mesmo assim é indireto e muito pouco. Segurança é depende de muitos fatores e nenhuma linguagem ou paradigma pode ajudar muito. O que pode ocorrer é dar mais facilidades para não cometer certos tipos de erro.

Minha experiência é que quem programava bem e sabia tornar o código seguro continuou fazendo isto da mesma forma programando orientado a objeto, ou até continuaram com programação imperativa. Quem não sabia o que estava fazendo e não aprendeu nada, ou está fazendo códigos mais confusos e inseguros com orientação a objeto ou está a mesma coisa. Se melhorou foi porque se informou melhor.

Em alguns casos OOP é usada para dar mais flexibilidade e isto pode abrir mais portas de ataques. Dependendo do que fizer, indiretamente OOP pode piorar a segurança. Mas é um enorme **pode** e mesmo assim é indireto. É que o paradigma apenas facilitou fazer algo que se temia em outro paradigma. Achei um [estudo que vai por este caminho](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1183092) propondo soluções. Mas quase ninguém fica sabendo dessas coisas e cometem os erros.

Para concluir, não existe receita de bolo para nada em programação a não ser coisas muito simples e de baixa exigência. Em segurança tem menos ainda. Tem que entender todos os fundamentos da computação de forma profunda, ganhar experiência, ser muito atento e disciplinado, e é claro, saber o que fazer em cada situação. Em geral se contrata um especialista em segurança quando isto realmente é importante. Caso contrário, faz-se o melhor possível e vai resolvendo as coisas conforme a necessidade.

Comment: É uma crença dos anos 90, achar que OOP resolve qualquer problema :)

Comment: @epx eu falo um pouco sobre isto http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80228/algoritmos-em-c-poo/80233#comment162891_80233 as pessoas aprendem no automático. É inacreditável como as pessoas gastam tanto tempo da vida deles, seguindo algo como se fosse religião e não procuram entender porque usam aquilo. E muitos cursos, livros e obviamente outros programadores "mais experientes" (em quantidade, não em qualidade) contribuem para perpetuar isto.

Comment: @bigown li a sua resposta que acho interessante... mas não percebo a sua afirmação: "Em alguns casos OOP é usado para dar mais flexibilidade e isto pode abrir mais portas de ataques."

Comment: @chambelix eu não sou especialista em segurança então não sei tudo o que pode acontecer. Mas sei o básico para dizer que se você usa certos padrões, você se expõe mais. Não disse que por causa do OOP você abre as portas, isto seria contraditório com todo o resto do que escrevi. Apenas disse que OOP facilita dar flexibilidade para a aplicação, coisa que antes talvez a pessoa não fizesse porque não sabia como fazer (isto está na resposta). Certas flexibilidades podem não ser bem pensadas e abrir estas portas. Percebe como é indireto? Vou dar um exemplo:

Comment: Imagine permitir que uma classe seja herdada e alguns algoritmos trabalhem com as classes filhas. Aì alguém não faz direito o que precisa ser feito na classe derivada e abre uma porta de exploração que não tinha na classe base. Pronto, você tem uma insegurança porque usou OOP. Mas não é culpa da OOP, é culpa do programador. Mas se não tivesse feito isto, talvez não teria dado a chance de acontecer isto.

Comment: Claro, a aplicação é diferente, não tem uma característica. E é claro também que o problema poderia ter acontecido se a característica tivesse sido colocada em uma aplicação codificada de forma imperativa. Então não é OOP que causou o problema.

Comment: @bigown entendo o seu ponto de vista... mas parece que você está então a confirmar um problema de herança de problemas... entendo! No entanto isso não infere em nada com ataques sequer em menor segurança, no meu entender claro. Cumprimentos pela resposta.

Comment: Eu recomendo usar OO mais pela questão de aumento na produtividade,  e fazendo testes unitários, dessa forma você obterá mais segurança em seus códigos, ou menos falhas de segurança. Todavia nada é seguro a ponto de ser inquebrável. Pode demorar mais tempo, mas um dia alguém pode invadir, isso vai depender de quanto vale a pena alguém dedicar seu tempo para isso, e da importância disso.

Comment: Se seu sistema não é do tipo `gmail.com`,  acredito que ninguém irá perder seu precioso tempo para achar brechas de segurança no seu sistema, a menos que ele já demonstre falhas básicas como sql injection, ou algo do tipo...