# É possível programar orientado a objeto em C?

Tags: c, orientação-a-objetos, engenharia-de-software

Existe a possibilidade de construir um programa em C utilizando POO?

Procurei em diversos sites exemplos disso, porém não achei nada concreto que me diga realmente se dá ou não. Se sim, por favor, coloque ao menos um exemplo de código.

Comment: Sugiro procurar entender melhor o que é POO. As respostas de **mgibsonbr** e **Luiz Vieira** [nesta pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/55493/14584) foram as únicas que vi até agora aqui no SOpt que oferecem uma definição útil e muito boa de POO. Programar orientado a objetos não se trata de codificar geniais truques tecnológicos para conseguir fazer herança e polimorfismo numa linguagem que não oferece isso como recurso natural. Programar orientado a objetos trata-se de utilizar seus conceitos numa linguagem que abstrai as técnicas que o compilador usa para fazer os conceitos funcionarem.

Comment: Eu não quero fazer POO em C, até porque sei que não tem como, eu quero "emular", para poder utilizar alguns recursos.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Vou dizer algo concreto: dá! Mas não costuma compensar na maioria dos casos. O que eu diria o mesmo para todo OOP :).

Talvez o melhor exemplo de programa feito em C que usa OOP seja o [GTK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GTK%2B) que usa todo sistema do [GObject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GObject) ([referência](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-The-Base-Object-Type.html)).

Tem até um [livro sobre o assunto](http://www.cs.rit.edu/%7Eats/books/ooc.pdf).

Inicialmente o C++ apenas gerava um código em C. O código era um tanto confuso, mas era um programa feito com técnicas de OOP (escrito originalmente em C++) e em vez de gerar um código binário, gerava um fonte em C.

Qualquer [linguagem de programação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102452/101) pode executar qualquer coisa. A diferença é o nível de abstração e eficiência que ela dá para construir códigos dentro de determinados padrões. De certa forma OOP é um padrão de projeto, não que seja definido assim, é só uma forma de abstração. [Padrões de projeto estão em todo lugar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/16204/101). Tudo pode ser aplicado em qualquer linguagem, a diferença é que algumas facilitam o trabalho.

[Assembly pode ser programado como OOP.](http://www.drdobbs.com/embedded-systems/object-oriented-programming-in-assembly/184408319)

Em C você teria que escrever códigos para lidar com tudo o que outras linguagens fazem em sua estrutura básica. Fica grande, confuso e feio, a maioria dos erros provavelmente só serão percebidos em tempo de execução, fora ser mais lento de desenvolver, vai ter muito trabalho manual, tem chance de causar mais problemas. Mas atende todas necessidades.

Você consegue produzir o encapsulamento, a herança e o polimorfismo que são [as três técnicas básicas da OOP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/215679/101). Pode também ter abstração e sobrecarga, como algumas definições do que é OOP entendem. Novamente, não fica bom, algumas técnicas talvez não compense o esforço necessário. Pode haver mais perda de performance do que em uma linguagem com sintaxe e semântica própria para OOP.

Nada disso quer dizer que C é uma linguagem OOP, apenas que é possível usar o mesmo padrão se você quiser muito.

Já respondi boa parte disto nessa [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53108/101).

Como o foco não é sobre os detalhes de como fazer isto vou deixar os *links* abaixo como informação adicional:

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/415452/221800
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/351733/221800
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/1237266/221800
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/1403890/221800
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/524033/221800

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Eu queria achar uma forma de apenas "separar" as coisas, não tendo que colocar tudo num arquivo só.

Comment: Não sei se entendi o que você chama de separar as coisas. Orientação a objeto tem muito a ver com juntar coisas. Mas você pode estar falando de outra coisa, de desacoplamento. Tem técnicas que não precisa ser OOP para organizar melhor o código.

Comment: Desconhecia esse lado do `C`, mas é vantagem programar assim? me refiro ao link do livro.

Comment: Um link que pode complementar http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/53151/3635

Comment: Meu objetivo inicial era conseguir "desacoplar" as coisas, separando em arquivos diferentes, mas como você comentou sobre encapsulamento, herança e polimorfismo utilizando C, isso seria um bônus de grande ajuda para mim.

Comment: @MeuChapeu em geral não. Mas a construção de uma GUI é tão complexa, que chega compensar. Pra falar a verdade GUI é uma das poucas coisas onde OOP realmente se encaixa perfeitamente. O resto é forçação de barra :) Claro, tudo tem momento para fazer. Mas se precisar fazer OOP mesmo, é melhor usar outra linguagem. Só se o C for requisito explícito é que se deve adotar esta solução. Era o caso do Gnome/GTK.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento achou o que eu estava procurando.

Comment: @JonathanBarcela depois eu tento complementar mas desacoplar não precisa de OOP. Não sei se isto cabe mais nesta pergunta que claramente é sobre OOP e não desacoplamento em linguagem imperativa.

Comment: @bigown Vamos deixar o foco em POO mesmo, quando ao desacoplamento eu crio outra pergunta, se necessário. Obrigado.

Comment: Monstrinhos como o GObject surgiram porque o compilador C++ livre (gcc) era considerado muito ruim, e também há/havia um certo preconceito da comunidade de software livre com C++. Os problemas do gcc foram resolvidos há muito tempo, então é muito mais fácil usar C++ e evitar os recursos mais esotéricos do mesmo para não se enrolar.

Comment: @epx, sim, isso mesmo. Também há alguma dificuldade de interoperabilidade com C++.

Answer (score 6):

O mais próximo da OO que a Linguagem C consegue chegar é usando TAD's (Tipos Abstratos de Dados).
E sim, você consegue "separar" a interface da implementação de um TAD em arquivos separados (na verdade, o ideal é que vc os separe).

Conceitualmente, um TAD é um conjunto de dados estruturados e as operações que podem ser executadas sobre esses dados.

Normalmente, implementa-se um TAD na forma de dois módulos (arquivos separados): a implementação e a interface.

As vantagens de uso de um TAD são: encapsulamento (uma característica da OO), a segurança, a flexibilidade e a reutilização (outra característica da OO).

Vou dar um exemplo para vc em um TAD simples, de um ponto em um espaço bidimensional. Vc vai criar 3 arquivos em um projeto (pode ser do CodeBlocks ou do DEV):

1. ponto.c
2. ponto. h e
3. testa_ponto.h

Seguem as implementações de todos eles, na ordem (o projeto funciona perfeitamente):
ARQUIVO ponto.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "ponto.h"

struct ponto {
    float x;
    float y;
};

Ponto *pto_cria (float x, float y){
    Ponto *p = (Ponto*) malloc(sizeof(Ponto));
    if (p == NULL) {
        printf("Memoria insuficiente!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    p->x = x;
    p->y = y;
    return p;
}

void pto_libera (Ponto *p){
    free(p);
}

void pto_acessa (Ponto *p, float *x, float *y){
    *x = p->x;
    *y = p->y;
}

void pto_atribui (Ponto *p, float x, float y){
    p->x = x;
    p->y = y;
}

float pto_distancia (Ponto *p1, Ponto *p2){
    float dx = p2->x - p1->x;
    float dy = p2->y - p1->y;
    return sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
}
```

ARQUIVO ponto.h

```
/* TAD: Ponto (x,y) */
/* Tipo exportado */
typedef struct ponto Ponto;

/* Funçőes exportadas */
/* Funçăo cria - Aloca e retorna um ponto com coordenadas (x,y) */
Ponto *pto_cria (float x, float y);

/* Funçăo libera - Libera a memória de um ponto previamente criado */
void pto_libera (Ponto * p);

/* Funçăo acessa - Retorna os valores das coordenadas de um ponto */
void pto_acessa (Ponto *p, float *x, float *y);

/* Funçăo atribui - Atribui novos valores ŕs coordenadas de um ponto */
void pto_atribui (Ponto *p, float x, float y);

/* Funçăo distancia - Retorna a distância entre dois pontos */
float pto_distancia (Ponto *p1, Ponto *p2);
```

ARQUIVO testa_ponto.c:

```
/* Funçăo : Exemplo de uso do TAD Ponto
/ Autor : Edkallenn
/ Data : 06/04/2012
/ Observaçőes: Salve este arquivo como testa_ponto.c
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "ponto.h"

int main (void)
{
    //float x, y;

    Ponto *p = pto_cria(2.0,1.0);
    Ponto *q = pto_cria(3.4,2.1);

    float d = pto_distancia(p,q);

    printf("Distancia entre pontos: %f\n",d);

    pto_libera(q);
    pto_libera(p);

    return 0;
}
```

PERCEBA que temos a definição do tipo (com os campos, "propriedades" ou "atributos" do tipo), temos as funções do tipo (ou os "métodos" que o tipo, ou objeto, como queira, pode executar) e temos o arquivo (que seria o main) que testa o tipo.

DETALHE: isso não é OO. Na prática, MUITAS das características da Orientação a Objetos estão de fora. Isso é bem próximo do que seria uma OO "suja" em uma linguagem procedural.

Entende?

Links para vc entender melhor...
Sobre TAD:

- [https://www.inf.ufes.br/~pdcosta/ensino/2011-2-estruturas-de-dados/slides/Aula8%28TADs%29.pdf](https://www.inf.ufes.br/%7Epdcosta/ensino/2011-2-estruturas-de-dados/slides/Aula8%28TADs%29.pdf)
- http://wiki.icmc.usp.br/images/f/fd/AulaTAD.pdf
- [https://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~marcio/cursos/dloads/prog3_C++/material/TAD.pdf](https://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/%7Emarcio/cursos/dloads/prog3_C++/material/TAD.pdf)
- https://blogdecodigo.wordpress.com/2012/08/02/tad-tipo-abstratos-de-dados/ (em java)

E os arquivos do projeto:
https://github.com/ed1rac/AulasEstruturasDados/tree/master/2016/TAD_ponto

Qualquer coisa, nos comentários.

Como o colega falou ali em cima, é muito trabalho! Se quiser usar OO parta para uma linguagem genuinamente OO como C++, Java ou C#.