# VBA é orientada a objeto?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, vba

VBA pode ser considerada uma linguagem orientado a objeto?

Apesar de possuir *getters and setters* (ou *letters*… rsrsrs), implementação de classes, métodos e atributos, não possui os conceitos de encapsulamento, herança, polimorfismo, etc (ou tem e eu desconheço?).

Caso haja métodos de implementar todos os conceitos de POO, gostaria muito de conhecer.

De qualquer forma, gostaria muito de saber se essa linguagem se enquadra neste conceito.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VBA na verdade é a linguagem Visual Basic e usa a versão 6, cujo último lançamento saiu há 20 anos. VB é orientada a objeto? Dizem que sim (há quem questione), e de fato boa parte do que se considera mecanismos de OOP está lá.

Os conceitos citados são exatamente isso, conceitos, por isso não está em nenhuma linguagem. Linguagens possuem mecanismos e não conceitos. Claro, existem mecanismos que suportam esses conceitos. VB permite polimorfismo, herança de subtipo e encapsulamento, embora não precise de um mecanismo específico para obter o conceito, claro, é melhor com ele.

Sempre é possível programar OO em qualquer linguagem, até Assembly. Veja mais em [É possível programar orientado a objeto em C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80228/101).

Mas nem tente. VBA existe para criar *scripts*, então não faz sentido usar orientação a objeto nela.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/VB.NET/Conceptual.md).

Comment: No link abaixo tem esse mesmo questionamento que eu fiz, o usuário Mathieu Guindon 
mostra exatamente o que vc falou, mostrou formas de aplicar POO ao VBA. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31858094/is-vba-an-oop-language-and-does-it-support-polymorphism. Só não entendi uma coisa, por que não é interessante aplicar POO ao VBA.

Comment: Não fiquei tão fã dessa resposta, me parece confundir algumas coisas.