# Como usar propriedade estática de uma classe em outra classe em PHP?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, variável-estática

Estou me aventurando no mundo da POO em PHP e me surgiu a seguinte dúvida.

Das quatro formas que usei no código abaixo, para atribuir o valor de `$prop1` da `MinhaClasse` à variável `$val` dentro do método `fazAlgumaCoisa()` da `OutraClasse`, qual seria a mais indicada em termos de performance e segurança?

*Obs.: favor levar em consideração que, além de `$prop1`, terei muitas outras propriedades semelhantes no mesmo código.*

```
<?php

class MinhaClasse {

    static $prop1 = 'Valor 1';

    public static function set($name,$val)
    {
        self::$$name = $val;
    }

    public static function get($name)
    {
        return self::$$name;
    }

}


class OutraClasse {

    public $propA;
    public $propB;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->setProps();
    }

    public function setProps()
    {
        $this->$propA = MinhaClasse::$prop1;
        $this->$propB = MinhaClasse::get('prop1');
    }

    public function fazAlgumaCoisa()
    {

        // Abaixo Diferentes forma de obter "Valor 1" da "MinhaClasse".

        $val = MinhaClasse::$prop1; // 'Valor 1'
        $val = MinhaClasse::get('prop1'); // 'Valor 1'
        $val = $this->$propA; // 'Valor 1'
        $val = $this->$propB; // 'Valor 1'

        // o método fará algo à mais a partir daqui...

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se quer performance e segurança eu reveria a ideia de usar PHP e [OOP não tem nada a ver com isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80085/101). Na verdade está fazendo menos OOP do que pensa. É comum as pessoas dizerem quem estão fazendo sem entender o que de fato é OOP, as pessoas acham que OOP é por em uma classe, e não é.

Está fazendo mais metaprogramação em certa medida que OOP e isto piora a performance, mas não muito porque já tem custos naturais quando usa classes. E quando usa algo estático está abrindo mão de trabalhar com o objeto em si.

Está falando de um exemplo artificial e OOP precisa de contexto, de entender os requisitos e modelar o objeto de acordo com a necessidade. Em exemplos artificiais nada disso existe ou aceita qualquer coisa, o que faz qualquer solução ser certa e errada ao mesmo tempo.

Propriedades estáticas só existem [na classe e não no objeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100812/101), então se está pensando em herança isso não é possível e não faz sentido.

Curiosamente dá para fazer tudo isso que está fazendo em PHP sem a classe de forma muito mais simples. PHP foi criado originalmente pra ter tudo estático e acessar  os membros de um certo tipo através de *strings* em vez código escrito. Por isso, está usando a ferramenta errada e complicando o que é simples. Se vai fazer OOP, todo este código está errado, ainda que funcione, se quer realmente fazer o que está nele, classe é a ferramenta inadequada.

Pode ajudar:

- [Chamar método estático de classe por variável estática](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/103796/101)
- [Como usar variáveis estáticas e globais em PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49521/101)
- [Qual a diferença entre static::Propriedade, NomeClasse::propriedade, self::propriedade?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/242625/101)
- [Quando faz sentido ter apenas métodos e atributos estáticos em uma classe?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/129983/101)

Comment: Entendi.. na verdade estou usando este código mais para aprender POO (OOP) mesmo, ai fiquei pensando qual seria a forma mais indicada de obter 'Valor 1' dentro do contexto que citei, seguindo as melhores práticas, convenções, etc...

De qualquer forma agradeço pela resposta. Vou analisar os links que citou. Obg

Comment: @robssanches Se eu te disser que "POO não é código", o que você responderia?

Comment: @Anderson Carlos Woss Agora eu diria que acredito que vc está certo e que POO não seria o código em si, mas sim a metodologia ou conceito usado por trás da escrita, para permitir a organização e possibilidade de reutilização do código.

Porém não sei se estou certo nessa definição...

Comment: @robssanches quais conceitos? E como o seu código se relaciona com eles?